# Where to find the default binding mode of a control bindable property?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

Whenever dealing with a [BindableProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.bindableproperty), there are 4 different binding modes:

1. TwoWay — data goes both ways between source and target
2. OneWay — data goes from source to target
3. OneWayToSource — data goes from target to source
4. OneTime — data goes from source to target, but only when the BindingContext changes

And as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode?view=net-maui-7.0) says:

> The default binding mode for most properties such as Rotation, Scale, and Opacity is OneWay.

However, anytime I read the documentation of a specific control and its bindable properties, I'm not able to find about their default binding mode (e.g. [Label TextProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.label.textproperty?view=net-maui-7.0))

Question is: how do I easily get the default binding mode of a control bindable property ?

Comment: In general, it's always OneWay except the property is read-only (OneWayToSource) or the control accepts user input, then it's TwoWay (to send the input back to the binding source). [Two-way bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode?view=net-maui-7.0#two-way-bindings). Unlike in WPF it is not explicitly documented. Maybe they will enhance the documentation.

Comment: As above, it's usually safe to assume OneWay, except when it's something that should be two way, like an entry. In case you're ever not sure though, the source code is available online to check! [Label.Text](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Label.cs#L30) .  Or [Input View Text](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/InputView.cs#L12) which is what entry text inherits from. Notice the default binding mode on the label text is not specified, meaning the default of OneWay, but the default is specified on the Input View Text

Comment: Thanks for the pinpoint to the source code, this will help for sure!
I initially thought I could find this information directly from the documentation of each control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Binding mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode?view=net-maui-7.0#two-way-bindings) docs say:

> Most bindable properties have a default binding mode of OneWay but
> some properties have a default binding mode of TwoWay, including the
> following:
>
> `Date` property of DatePicker
>
> `Text` property of Editor, Entry, SearchBar, and EntryCell
>
> `IsRefreshing` property of ListView
>
> `SelectedItem` property of MultiPage
>
> `SelectedIndex` and SelectedItem properties of Picker
>
> `Value` property of Slider and Stepper
>
> `IsToggled` property of Switch
>
> `On` property ofSwitchCell
>
> `Time` property of TimePicker

If there are control binding modes you are not sure about, you can [check the source code of Maui](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/find/main) to determine, for example, the BindingMode of ValueProperty of [Slider](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/Slider.cs#:%7E:text=static%20readonly%20BindableProperty-,ValueProperty,-%3D%20BindableProperty.) is TwoWay.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't notice that list actually, this is helpful.
Somehow I thought I could find this information directly from the documentation of each control (e.g. from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.slider)